# How to evaluate the integral $\int x^2/\sqrt{4-x^2}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to compute this integral?
$$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx$$

If there were $x$ instead of $x^2$ in the numerator I know how to do a substitution $y=4-x^2$. But this doesn't help with the $x^2$.

Comment: You have no idea how to solve the problem? Or to write out the integral?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use the substitution $$x = 2\sin\theta\implies dx=2\cos\theta\,d\theta$$

and $$x^2 = (2\sin\theta)^2 = 4\sin^2\theta$$

Then you get the integral $$\int \frac{(x^2)(\,dx)}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}= \int \frac{(4\sin^2 \theta)\,(2 \cos\theta\,d\theta)}{2\;\underbrace{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}_{\sqrt{\cos^2 \theta}}} = \quad 4\int \sin^2 \theta\,d\theta$$

Can you take it from here?

---

**Remark** regarding your proposed substitution:
If you want to use the substitution $y = 4-x^2$, you are going to perform a lot of work and end up with an unhelpful result: $y = 4-x^2\implies dy = -2x\,dx$,  and $x = \pm\sqrt{4-y}$ gives you $$-\frac 12 \int\frac{x\cdot (-2x\,dx)}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} = \frac 12\int \frac{\pm \sqrt{4-y}\,dy}{y^{1/2}}= -\frac 12\int \pm \sqrt{\frac{4-y}{y}}\,dy$$

Answer (score 3):

No trigonometric substitution. Use $x=2t$ and reduce to
$$
\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\,dx
=
4\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt
$$
So we have to compute
$$
\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt
$$
and we do it by parts:
\begin{align}
I=\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt
&=
\int(-t)\frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt\\[2ex]
&=
(-t)\sqrt{1-t^2}-\int(-1)\sqrt{1-t^2}\,dt\\[2ex]
&=
-t\sqrt{1-t^2}+\int\frac{1-t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt\\[2ex]
&=
-t\sqrt{1-t^2}+\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt-
\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt\\[2ex]
&=
-t\sqrt{1-t^2}+\arcsin t-I
\end{align}
Thus
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}(\arcsin t-t\sqrt{1-t^2})
$$
Therefore
$$
\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\,dx=
4\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left(\arcsin\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}\right)
=2\arcsin\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{4-x^2}
$$